# Can I use css3 not selector with pseudo class?

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
p:not(p:first-letter)
{
color:#000;
}
</style>

<p style="color:Blue">
  test test
</p>
```

It's not working as expected as all the letters of paragraph should be in black except first.

Comment: `p:not(...)` filters out all the `p` elements which match `...`. No `p` elements match `p:first-letter`. Also, `:not()` doesn't accept pseudo-elements, so this won't work in the first place.

Comment: To be clear, `:first-letter` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class as you say.

Answer (score 1):

No. 
the `first-letter` pseudo-element is not part of the collection returned by the `p` selector. You can't exclude it then.
Why don't you just use :

```
<style type="text/css">
p
{
color:#000;
}
p:first-letter{
    color:blue;
}
</style>

<p style="color:Blue">
  test test
</p>
```

By the way, this is not a good practice at all. You should use a class on your p element and style via css. You don't need to generate css dynamically for that.

```
<style type="text/css">
p.test
{
color:#000;
}
p.test:first-letter{
    color:blue;
}
</style>

<p class="test">
  test test
</p>
```

Comment: I want to add color in style attribute because the color is from database and I can't make css dynamic.

Comment: so -1... Cool... First, inline css is "bad". You should use a class. Second, my solution works. I'm just trying to help you man.

Comment: The asker cannot downvote, so it was someone else who did. Not sure why, because the answer is correct.

Comment: Oh! Didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. @gaurav nevermind! Getting cooler now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, [:not(X)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

That means you cant use `::first-letter` as an argument of `:not()`, because it's a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FPseudo-elements).

Try the other way around:

http://jsfiddle.net/YET8v/1/

HTML:

```
<p>Test test</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    color: #000;
}

p::first-letter {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The css selector not only takes simple selectors as parameter.

A simple selector is: a single element, attribute selector, class, id or pseude-class.

Examples of simple selectors:

```
body
*
[value="foo"]
.foo
#foo
:hover
```